# How do I convert 10 to .10 or 10% in javascript?

Tags: javascript, math

The third-party is feeding me 10 percent as the number 10.
In my code how do I move the decimal 2 places over for the variable itemDiscountPercent?

```
        if (boolActive)
    {
        itemDiscountPercent = Math.percent(ogCookie.products[i].discount_percent);
        itemPrice = ogCookie.products[i].price;
        itemQty = ogCookie.products[i].quantity;

        if (itemQty > 1)
        {
            itemDiscountPercent = itemDiscountPercent * itemQty;
        }

        priceDiscount = itemPrice * itemDiscountPercent;

        alert(itemDiscountPercent);
        alert(itemPrice);
        alert(priceDiscount);

    }
```

So instead of getting 299.8 for a line item with quantity 2, I need it to be 2.99 so I can subtract it later in the code.

Comment: uhhh....  divide by 100...

Comment: @jondavidjohn ^_^ glad to add it :-)

Answer (score 3):

divide by 100.

```
var dec = itemDiscountPercent / 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (boolActive)
{
    itemDiscountPercent = ogCookie.products[i].discount_percent;
    itemPrice = ogCookie.products[i].price;
    itemQty = ogCookie.products[i].quantity;

    //priceDiscount = itemPrice * itemQty * itemDiscountPercent / 100;
    priceDiscount = Math.round(itemPrice * itemQty * itemDiscountPercent - 0.5) / 100;

    alert(itemDiscountPercent);
    alert(itemPrice);
    alert(priceDiscount);

}
```

Comment: or if you want the result with two decimals (truncated):
priceDiscount = Math.round(itemPrice * itemQty * itemDiscountPercent - 0.5) / 100;